# Gracefully take down a Zookeeper Node

Tags: zookeeper

I have had a hard disk begin to fail on one of my Zookeeper nodes in a cluster of 3 nodes. It is only a matter of time until the disk dies completely. Rather than waiting for this, I'd like to remove this node from the cluster *gracefully* as it is currently online in the cluster.

Turns out Zookeeper is not incredibly well documented; I cannot find out the safe/proper way to remove a node from a cluster via Google or the small amount of documentation I can find on [Apache's site](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html).

What steps or CLI commands should I use to gently take down this node such that my 2-node majority will be fine in the interim while I get the disk replaced on the dying node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would have already worked your way around this but this came up in one of my search and so I wanted to share my inputs -

- From the bin directory in ZK_HOME, please execute ./zkServer.sh stop and replace your drive or any other maintenance you require.

Since you have a 3 node cluster, having one node down is OK as remaining 2 is still a majority. Reads/writes should continue to happen as new leader would be elected automatically once you take the node down